# Breaking loop when "warnings()" appear in R

Tags: r, loops, warnings, break

I am having an issue:
  I am running a loop to process multiple files.  My matrices are enormous and therefore I often run out of memory if I am not careful.

Is there a way to break out of a loop if any warnings are created?   It just keeps running the loop and reports that it failed much later... annoying.  Any ideas oh wise stackoverflow-ers?!

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can turn warnings into errors with:

```
options(warn=2)
```

Unlike warnings, errors will interrupt the loop. Nicely, R will also report to you that these particular errors were converted from warnings.

```
j <- function() {
    for (i in 1:3) {
        cat(i, "\n")
        as.numeric(c("1", "NA"))
}}

# warn = 0 (default) -- warnings as warnings!
j()
# 1 
# 2 
# 3 
# Warning messages:
# 1: NAs introduced by coercion 
# 2: NAs introduced by coercion 
# 3: NAs introduced by coercion 

# warn = 2 -- warnings as errors
options(warn=2)
j()
# 1 
# Error: (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Afterwards, use `options(warn=1) ` to restore the default setting.

Comment: The default value is 0 though.  So to restore the _factory settings_ use `options("warn"=0)`.

Comment: Resetting options in R is usually best handled by 1) `op=options(warn=2)`, 2) doing your thing, and then 3) reset with `options(op)`, which takes you back to `warn=0` in this case.

Answer (score 49):

R allows you to define a condition handler

```
x <- tryCatch({
    warning("oops")
}, warning=function(w) {
    ## do something about the warning, maybe return 'NA'
    message("handling warning: ", conditionMessage(w))
    NA
})
```

which results in

```
handling warning: oops
> x
[1] NA
```

Execution continues after tryCatch; you could decide to end by converting your warning to an error

```
x <- tryCatch({
    warning("oops")
}, warning=function(w) {
    stop("converted from warning: ", conditionMessage(w))
})
```

or handle the condition gracefully (continuing evaluation after the warning call)

```
withCallingHandlers({
    warning("oops")
    1
}, warning=function(w) {
    message("handled warning: ", conditionMessage(w))
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

which prints

```
handled warning: oops
[1] 1
```

Comment: +1 -- Excellent. I had thought of mentioning this option, but could not have put together such a short but sweet tutorial.

Comment: having a demonstration with a nice `for` would be even better :)

Answer (score 38):

Set the global `warn` option:

```
options(warn=1)  # print warnings as they occur
options(warn=2)  # treat warnings as errors
```

Note that a "warning" is not an "error".  Loops don't terminate for warnings (unless `options(warn=2)`).