# Locating source of knitr data.table warning message in original code

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio, knitr

I'd like to locate the specific chunk (or better yet, line of code) that generates a warning message when compiling a knitr PDF in RStudio. This is the final piece of info that knitr outputs after successfully running every chunk:

> ```
> .....
> output file: file.tex
>
> [1] "file.tex"
> Warning message:
> In bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- FALSE, xo, roll = 0,  :
>   A known encoding (latin1 or UTF-8) was detected in a join column. data.table compares the 
> bytes currently, so doesn't support *mixed* encodings well; i.e., using both latin1 and UTF-8, 
> or if any unknown encodings are non-ascii and some of those are marked known and others not. 
> But if either latin1 or UTF-8 is used exclusively, and all unknown encodings are ascii, then 
> the result should be ok. In future we will check for you and avoid this warning if everything 
> is ok. The tricky part is doing this without impacting performance for ascii-only cases.
> Running xelatex on file.tex...completed
>
> Created PDF: ~/Documents/file.pdf
> ```

Why is the warning not displayed with the chunk that generated it? In an effort to locate its source, I've tried turning on `opts_chunk$set(warning=TRUE, message=TRUE, echo=TRUE`, but the warning message doesn't show up in the final PDF. I've also stepped through the many chunks individually and don't seem to get this warning in the R console (in fact I only employ a single `merge()` and the `by=` is an integer). Any other suggestions for tracking it down? I'm running the latest CRAN versions of knitr 1.8 and data.table 1.94, along with RStudio 0.98.1091.

Comment: Maybe try setting `options(warn=2)`, to turn warnings into errors [as, e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217901/breaking-loop-when-warnings-appear-in-r/8217929#8217929)?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks, using `options(warn=1)  # print warnings as they occur` pushed the error to display in the knitr output right where it occurred (it turns out it was from an inline expression between two chunks). Super helpful.

Comment: Aha, very cool. I'll have to keep in mind that bit about warnings in inline expressions. Hadn't thought of that.