# Loop interruption when warning is encountered with TryCatch in R

Tags: r

I use `tryCatch` to handle warnings and errors in order to write a log file and secure my code. It write the log correctly with `cat` when `tryCatch` returns a success or an error but my problem is the loop execution is stopped when a warning is encountered.

Whitout the `tryCatch` the loop is not interrupted by `warning()` so it is not clear for me what's happening here because warning should not beaks loop.

[Breaking loop when "warnings()" appear in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217901/breaking-loop-when-warnings-appear-in-r)

Loop not interrupted :

```
>list <- c(1:10)
    for(i in list){
      warning(i)}

Warning: 1
Warning: 2
Warning: 3
Warning: 4
Warning: 5
Warning: 6
Warning: 7
Warning: 8
Warning: 9
Warning: 10
>
```

Loop interrupted :

```
>tryCatch(
  {
    list <- c(1:10)
    for(i in list){
      warning(i)
    }
  },
  error=function(cond) {
    message("ERROR: ", cond)
  },
  warning=function(cond) {
    message("WARNING: ", cond)
  } 
)

WARNING: simpleWarning in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): 1
>
```

Thank you,

Comment: what was the original warning message ?

Comment: It's `There is a warning downloading the symbols list, here's the original warning:
missing values removed from data`

Comment: could you run in debug mode and examine on which case is a warning created? Is it that if a warning occurs, You are still assigning it to "download" and later when you use "download" it errors out! We will need more details on what/when an warning occurs and at that situation what gets assigned to "download"

Comment: Hi Joel, the warning is created when `to.weekly` is called because there are `NA` in the xts. But this is not a problem when `tryCatch` doesn't handle errors and warnings (i.e. the loop continues without being interrupted). I could prevent this warning by applying `na.omit()` to the `ticker` object but this is not a solution to me because I want to log further & unexpected warnings and errors.

Comment: I changed the code above with a reproductible example. Hope it's help.