# How to make warnings explicit when converting from string to logical produces NAs

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function that catches conversion errors when a value is coerced to NA. It seems like the base conversion functions are inconsistent in returning warnings.

```
> as.numeric("a")
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

However, the warning is not shown when converting to logical:

```
> as.logical("a")
[1] NA
```

**My question**: Is there a way to make the warning explicit when a string cannot be converted to logical?

I have looked into `rlang::as_logical()`, but it returns an error instead of a warning, that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `options(warn =`. For example:

```
options(warn=1, error=NULL)
```

to get a warning.

I typically handle this by promoting warnings to errors for the relevant part of the code.

For example:

```
options(warn=2, error=NULL)
as.logical(x)
```

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

You can also easily reset it like this `options(warn=0, error=NULL)`

Related: [Breaking loop when "warnings()" appear in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217901/breaking-loop-when-warnings-appear-in-r)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to do the trick! I'd like to get it as a warning though, so I'm using `options(warn = 1)`

Comment: @TamasNagy Great! Glad it helped. Sorry I misunderstood that you wanted an error rather than a warning. I can update it as such.

Comment: Finally, I went with `rlang::as_logical`, and handled failed conversions as errors instead of warnings, but this is still a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own function about this:

```
as.logical2 <- function(x) {

  if (is.na(x)) return(x)
  out <- as.logical(x)
  #if there is an NA, you can issue a warning
  if (is.na(out)) warning('NAs introduced by coercion')
  out

}

as.logical2('a')
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In as.logical2("a") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Hm, and what if the original value was an NA? This function would (mis)label it as coercion fail. E.g. `as.logical2(NA)`

Comment: Now it takes care of that as well @TamasNagy. Updated the code.