# How to retry a function forever on any type of failure in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, websocket, try-catch

I am working with socket connections between R and a web-page. The code works well but at random times it stops for one of many likely reasons. For instance, most commonly R closes the socket with warnings like:

"handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)"
"Unhandled promise error: invalid state"

but other reasons for stopping can include the server stops communication, the server ask for confirmation, etc..

The solution is to re-start the connection.

I have put all this functionality into a single function and was hopping to create an infinite loop using the trycatch function and try the function again when it failed. This unfortunately did not work as sometimes the connection was simply stopped with a warning but not an error.

The code below captures, I believe, the nature of the problem:

```
Connect<- function() {X= runif(1); if (X < .5 ) stop(); Sys.sleep(1); return(X) } #stopping function
p=1
while (p==1){
tryCatch({Connect()}, error=function(e) {Connect()})
}
```

One would expect for this code to always print a random number without stopping.
The question is how can one implement an infinite loop that re-run a likely to fail function, each time it fails, for any reason?

Comment: You could "upgrade" the warning like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217929/20513099

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The problem I see with this option of turning warnings into errors, is that any other "non-lethal" warning will also stop the code.

Comment: Just add an event for warnings. You can add logic to handle different warnings separately. See [How to write try-catch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the stopping function again in the error handler, leave that out (optionally printing the error message), otherwise on failing it will run the stopping function again without attempting to catch further errors. You can similarly catch warnings:

```r
Connect <-
  function() {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    X = runif(1)
    if (X < .5) stop("Oops too low!")
    if (X > 0.9) warning("This is a high X!")
    cat(X, "\n")
  } 

while (TRUE) {
  tryCatch({
    Connect()
  }, error = function(e) {
    cat("Error:", e$message, "\n")
  }, warning = function(w) {
    cat("Warning:", w$message, "\n")
  })
}
#> 0.8085583 
#> Error: Oops too low! 
#> Error: Oops too low! 
#> 0.6671211 
#> 0.7245536 
#> Error: Oops too low! 
#> Warning: This is a high X! 
#> 0.7840508 
...
```

An alternative to the `while` loop is to create a safe-calling function with the `tryCatch` statement within it and recursively call the function when it finishes the `tryCatch` statement:

```r
safe_loop <- function() {
  tryCatch(
    Connect(),
    error = function(e) {
      cat("Error:", e$message, "\n")
    }, warning = function(w) {
      cat("Warning:", w$message, "\n")
    }
  )
  safe_loop()
}

safe_loop()
#> 0.6366205 
#> Warning: This is a high X! 
#> 0.5966964 
#> Error: Oops too low! 
#> 0.8586928 
#> Error: Oops too low! 
...
```

### Side note - DO NOT try recursive call in `finally` statement

Today I learned that this crashes R:

```r
unquittable_recursion <- function() {
  tryCatch(Sys.sleep(1),
           finally = unquittable_recursion()
  )
}

unquittable_recursion()
```

### Update - only repeat if fails

```r
set.seed(100)

Connect <-
  function() {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    X = runif(1)
    if (X < .5) stop("Oops too low!")
    if (X > 0.9) warning("This is a high X!")
    cat(X, "\n")
  } 

safe_loop <- function() {
  tryCatch({
    failed <- TRUE
    Connect()
    failed <- FALSE
  },
  error = function(e) {
    cat("Error:", e$message, "\n")
  }, warning = function(w) {
    cat("Warning:", w$message, "\n")
  })
  if(failed) safe_loop()
}

safe_loop()
#> Error: Oops too low! 
#> Error: Oops too low! 
#> 0.5523224
```

Comment: thanks @Andy Baster I tried this command, unfortunately, the while function keeps on triggering the connection. Can you think of a way to run the function again, only if it fails?... some how we need to force the computer to be idle waiting for an error or a warning... not only right away after the fucntion is run.

Comment: Ah do you mean to only repeat connection attempt if it fails? I've put up some other code which might work better. What triggers the connection? Is it timed or has an external trigger, or should it always remain connected?

Comment: yes, the idea is to always remain connected.

Comment: Apologies, beyond what I'd suggest above I'm not sure what could be the best approach. Solution 1 with the while loop will re-run `connect()` whenever the function exits, even if it was successful. Solution 2 will re-run it if the function fails. If the function is somehow finishing and exiting whilst connection is still active then I'm not sure from the above code how to keep listening for an error.